# Чтение файла и запись из буфера в массив

Tags: массивы, golang

**У меня есть `test.txt` в нем 10 разных строк. Мне нужно прочитать и записать в массив построчно.**

Код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    str := string(bs)
    fmt.Println(str)
    strs := strings.Split(str, "\r\n")
    fmt.Println(strs) // выводится последняя строка файла + ]
}
```

Вывод:

```
0.0.0.0:80
110.172.167.34:8080
110.5.98.234:3128
110.8.253.100:80
113.6.255.107:80
114.30.47.10:80
114.30.79.62:8080
115.124.67.54:80
116.68.172.35:8080
116.84.187.131:3128
117.102.93.138:80
117.102.95.114:3128
117.35.118.2:3128
118.175.14.108:3128
118.220.175.207:80
118.46.147.201:3128
118.96.102.181:3128
118.96.110.41:3128
118.96.121.70:3128
118.96.148.40:3128
118.96.24.227:8080
118.96.87.107:3128

[0.0.0.0:80 110.172.167.34:8080 110.5.98.234:3128 110.8.253.100:80 113.6.255.107:80 114.30.47.10:80 114.30.79.62:8080 11
5.124.67.54:80 116.68.172.35:8080 116.84.187.131:3128 117.102.93.138:80 117.102.95.114:3128 117.35.118.2:3128 118.175.14
.108:3128 118.220.175.207:80 118.46.147.201:3128 118.96.102.181:3128 118.96.110.41:3128 118.96.121.70:3128 118.96.148.40
:3128 118.96.24.227:8080 118.96.87.107:3128 ]
```

Добавил код для выбора прокси сервера:

```
str := string(bs)
strs := strings.Split(str, "\r\n")
bestProxyServer := randInt(len(strs))
fmt.Print(strs)

proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(str[bestProxyServer])
httpClient := &http.Client { Transport: &http.Transport { Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl) } }
response, err := httpClient.Get(host)
```

Из среза ничего не выбирается, остается мой прежний ip адрес.

Вывод:

```
[110.5.98.234:3128 110.8.253.100:80 113.6.255.107:80 114.30.47.10:80 114.30.79.62:8080 115.124.67.54:80 116.68.172.35:80
80 116.84.187.131:3128]map[Date:[Mon, 06 Nov 2017 15:59:37 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html; charset=UTF-8] Set-Cookie:[PHPS
ESSID=tknp6t8h5m6rmptdb8cvef1so2; path=/ IP%5B1509983977%5D=**92.53.213.181**; expires=Sun, 04-Feb-2018 15:59:37 GMT; Max-Ag
e=7776000; path=/; domain=.2ip.ru] Server:[nginx] Connection:[keep-alive] Expires:[Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT] Cache-
Control:[no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate] Pragma:[no-cache]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уверены, что файл маленький, то дальше вам просто нужно разделить строку по `\n`:

```
strs := strings.Split(str, "\n")
```

Если файл большой, то лучше использовать `bufio.Scanner`. [Пример](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines) есть в документации.

Comment: Пишет что не может использовать strs как строку в массиве: cannot use strs (type []string) as type string in array or slice literal

Comment: @JackSmith Вы что-то странное делаете. `strs` - это и есть слайс строк из вашего файла. Зачем вы суёте их в другой слайс?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/oj-_Dim_B3

Comment: @JackSmith, еще раз, strs _уже_ срез. Хотите добавить его в другой - используйте _append_ .

Comment: @GreenDragon это я уже понял, исправил. но только у меня читается последняя строка файла тоесь 118.46.147.201:3128 и добавляется ] = 118.46.147.201:3128] у меня не читаются все 14 строк файле, читается только одна последняя строка. Что делать?

Comment: @Ainar-G у меня читается только последняя строка файла и добавляется знак ] что делать?

Comment: @JackSmith Телепаты празднуют День Народного Единства. Обновите вопрос с новым кодом.

Comment: @Ainar-G обновил

Comment: @JackSmith Ваш файл случаем не из ОС Windows? Если да, то попробуйте разделять по `"\r\n"` вместо `"\n"`

Comment: @Ainar-G выводит все построчно, но при этом добавляет не разбитый array в одну сплошную строку, добавил в ответ .

Comment: @JackSmith Это всего-лишь представление среза строк. Ваша задача выполнена. Делайте с этими строками то, что хотели.

Comment: @Ainar-G интересно... у меня не выбирается рандомный прокси сервер из среза, все делал как вы сказали, только сделал данный процесс рандомным. не понимаю что не так.

Comment: @JackSmith Это уже новый вопрос. Задавайте его отдельным вопросом. И добавьте код вашей функции randInt. Этот вопрос, как мне кажется, исчерпан.

Comment: @Ainar-G хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Генератор чисел по умолчанию является детерминированным, поэтому по умолчанию он будет каждый раз выдавать одну и ту же последовательность чисел. Чтобы создать различные последовательности, используйте seed.

из [документации](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#pkg-overview)

> Random numbers are generated by a Source. Top-level functions, such as
> Float64 and Int, use a default shared Source that produces a
> deterministic sequence of values each time a program is run. Use the
> Seed function to initialize the default Source if different behavior
> is required for each run.

вам надо использовать соль перед использованием рандома

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

или же

```
s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
r1 := rand.New(s1)
fmt.Print(r1.Intn(100))
```